# How can i add a time elapsed progrerss to my backgroundworker dowork event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In top of form1

```
label5.Text = "00:00:00";
```

In the dowork event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo diri = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\c-sharp");
            WalkDirectoryTree(diri);
        }
```

WalkDirectoryTree method

```
int tfiles = 0;
        int tdirs = 0;
        void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
            string[] workerResult = new string[4];
            try
            {
                files = root.GetFiles("*.cs");
                tdirs ++;
                workerResult[1] = root.FullName;
                workerResult[3] = tdirs.ToString();
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0,workerResult);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {

            }

            catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {

            }

            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
                {
                    tfiles += files.Length;
                    if (files.Length > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int Vara = File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName).Contains("Form1") ? 1 : 0;

                            if (Vara == 1)
                            {
                                workerResult[2] = files[0].FullName;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    workerResult[0] = tfiles.ToString();
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, workerResult);
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                subDirs = root.GetDirectories();
                foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
                {
                    WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
                }
            }
        }
```

In the constructor i start the backgroundworker

```
InitializeComponent();

            label1.Visible = false;
            label2.Visible = false;
            label3.Visible = false;
            label4.Visible = false;
            label5.Text = "00:00:00";
            pbt.Size = new Size(984, 23);
            pbt.Location = new Point(12, 358);
            this.Controls.Add(pbt);

            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I want to make that once the backgroundworker start the whole process start in the dowork event report to label5 the time elapsed.

First how can i do it ? and should i use a timer or stopwatch ?

Comment: Neither, always measure elapsed time with a clock.  DateTime.UtcNow.  Use the Timer only to update the label.  Its Interval value isn't very critical, the default of 100 msec is fine.  Don't pick 1000, that's going to get you to miss a second update once in a while.  Nyquist's sampling theorem at work.

Comment: @HansPassant - strongly disagree... `Stopwatch` is specifically designed to measure elapsed time.  Why would you recommend `DateTime`?

Comment: Sigh.  It is designed to measure very small intervals. It is not a clock, isn't as efficient as the clock, and does not agree with the clock.  But sure, nobody waits long enough, or checks, to find out.

Comment: The clock is less *accurate* for measuring elapsed time because it can drift, be adjusted by the OS, be updated by w32tm on NTP sync, and be manually manipulated by the user.  Stopwatch has none of these issues - so it is more *accurate*.  Sure, it's *precision* decreases the longer it runs, but it's on the order of milliseconds. So if you're measuring longer intervals, you probably don't care about that, and if you're measuring smaller intervals then you get the benefit of the higher precision... Haven't we discussed this before? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are wanting to measure the elapsed time taken by a process, by definition you should be using the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class.  [MSDN defines it as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

> **Stopwatch Class**
>
> Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure elapsed time.

However, you will *also* need a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` control on your form in order to update the field while the work is in progress.  The timer's `Interval` property controls how often you want to update the field, but don't rely on this to determine the actual value to display.  Instead, use the `Elapsed` property of the stopwatch.

1. Drop a `Timer` onto your form.
2. Create an instance of the stopwatch class in your C# code:

   ```
   private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
   ```
3. Just before you call `RunWorkerAsync()`, call `timer1.Start()`
4. Inside the background worker's `DoWork` event:

   ```
   _stopwatch.Restart();
   // do your work
   _stopwatch.Stop();
   ```
5. In the timer's `Tick` event, update your label with the value of the stopwatch's `Elapsed` property.  Format it however you like.

   ```
   lblElapsed.Text = _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.f");
   ```
6. In the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, call `timer1.Stop()`

[I've posted a complete working example here](https://github.com/mj1856/WinFormsTimerDemo).

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about displaying only the total time it took for the `BackgroundWorker` to do its job (i.e. not incremental updates):

Grab a timestamp (e.g. `DateTime.UtcNow`, if you don't need sub-millisecond precision) just prior to invoking `RunWorkerAsync`.  Pass this value into the `RunWorkerAsync` method (using the overload that accepts an `object` parameter).  Catch the `RunWorkerCompleted` event in your form, and retrieve the timestamp from the `UserState` property of those event args.  Set your label to the delta of the current time minus the `UserState`'s timestamp.

For example:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(DateTime.UtcNow);

// elsewhere in your form:
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _myLabel.Text = DateTime.UtcNow - (DateTime)e.UserState;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will update the text only once at the end.

Comment: @Shago, correct.  I thought that's what the OP was asking for.  I've updated the answer to clarify this.  Thanks!

Comment: You really don't want to use `DateTime.Now` for this.  See #1 and #2 [in this blog post of mine](http://codeofmatt.com/2015/03/06/common-daylight-saving-time-mistakes-for-net-developers/).

Comment: @MattJohnson, fair enough -- I was mainly trying to demonstrate the approach of capturing a timestamp prior to RunWorkerAsync, and then accessing that timestamp in the RunWorkerCompleted event.  Good point, though -- there are better ways to capture the timestamp that `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @MattJohnson updated the answer above to reflect use of `UtcNow` instead of `Now`.

Comment: No i want to make like a timer to display the time elapsed in real time. Not only in the end.

Comment: Sounds like @Shago's answer is the way to go then!

Answer (score 1):

I would capture the current time on a variable or field and start a timer before the invocation of `RunWorkerAsync`. On each tick of the timer update the label with the elapsed time (current time minus captured starting time). Stop the timer when the worker ends using `RunWorkerCompleted` event.